# How can I customize the links in the jekyll-theme-minimal theme?

Tags: github-pages, jekyll-theme

I have setup a [GitHub Page](https://jacoblundeen.github.io/) using the `jekyll-theme-minimal theme`.
Currently, the links in the description section of my `config_yml` file uses plain anchor tags:

```
<a href="/">View My LinkedIn Profile</a>
```

However this does not look great on my website. I want to change the style of the links to something similar as shown below but I can't seem to figure it out.

[image]

The GitHub repository for the website can be found [here](https://github.com/jacoblundeen/jacoblundeen.github.io).

Comment: You will have to write your own HTML + CSS code to achieve this. A simpler method to achieve a similar effect would be to use emojis instead of the icons and then remove the `View My` part. For example use `<a href="your-link"> LinkedIn</a>` instead of `<a href="your-link">View My LinkedIn Profile</a> ` in the config_yml.

Comment: @Bunny Thank you very much, got it to work that way. Follow up question, the theme automatically puts in the "View My Github Profile" at the bottom. Any idea how to force that to use an emoji as well?

Comment: Go to the `default.html` file in the `_layouts` folder and edit [line 30](https://github.com/jacoblundeen/jacoblundeen.github.io/blob/master/_layouts/default.html#L30)

Comment: If my answer helped you, make sure to accept it so that stack overflow marks this question as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## How to replace the links with clickable icons

You will have to write your own HTML (and possibly CSS code) in `config_yml` to achieve this. If you want to use the same icons, you will have to import the icons (maybe using a CDN).

A simpler method to achieve a similar effect would be to use emojis instead of the icons and then remove the `View My` part. For example you could use `<a href="your-link"> LinkedIn</a>` instead of `<a href="your-link">View My LinkedIn Profile</a>`  in the `config_yml`.

## How to further customize the theme

Edit the `default.html` file in the `_layouts` folder.